# C++: how to write this abstract class?

Tags: c++

I want to define an abstract class for a finite state machine.

```cpp
class State
{
  virtual State transit(const Input &i) = 0;
};
```

The idea is that I want a prototype function "transit" which takes the input and transit to the next state. Unfortunately, compiler won't allow this.

Is there a way to provide an abstract class like that?

What I think is to provide an abstract of state machine, the logic of how to run the state machine doesn't need to change for a set of problems, like taking the input and moving on to the next state, etc. But this abstraction doesn't care how state and input are defined, maybe something like below.

```cpp
template<S, I>
class StateMachine
{
  public:
    void set_initial_state(const S &is)
    {
        current_state = is;
    }
    void take_input(const I &input)
    {
        S next_state = current_state.transit(input);
        current_state = next_state;
    }
  private:
    S current_state;
};
```

When using this template, I would like to provide more hint to "S". For example, it must have a "transit" function. That's what I come for the idea of abstract class of "State".

Comment: Please explain *Unfortunately, compiler won't allow this.*?  What you have is a pure abstract class.

Comment: Abstract classes can't be instantiated, that's the reason for the compiler error. You are trying to return an Instance of State. You should return a pointer instead.

Comment: @Gerard097 or a smart pointer wrapped pointer for `State`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. 
Your compiler cannot let you return a State object, because it has `incomplete type` and therefor it doesn't know how to construct this. You probably want return a reference to `this` like for instance the operator<< of cout does.

Because you have not really specified what your overall design will look like, i cannot help you very much, but i think for a statemachine it is usually nice to have one `StateMachine` with an `enum class` inside for all states. Something like

```
class StateMachine {
   enum class State{
     state1,
     state2,
   };
   virtual void changeState(State to) { /* do Something */}
};
```

Comment: I add a few more edits to clarify my problem. Thanks.